# Express rational function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ in the form $u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, rational-functions, analytic-functions

Simple question. I have the function $f(z) = \frac{4z+1}{z^3+z}$ defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,i,-i\}$.

I want to show the function is analytic on its domain of definition. To do so, I want to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold everywhere, plus some other sufficient conditions for differentiability.

To do this, I want to find $u$ and $v$ such that 
$$ f(z) = \frac{4z+1}{z^3+z} = u(x,y) + iv(x,y) $$
for $z = x+iy$. I've tried fiddling around with it but haven't gotten anywhere. Any ideas?

Alternate approaches to show that $f$ is analytic on its domain are welcome.

Comment: If you plug in $z=x+iy$, do some algebra, you should easily be able to split it up into its real and imaginary parts.  Then, just use the Cauchy Riemann equations to show it is analytic on the domain.  Where are you running into trouble exactly?

Comment: You just reminded me that realising the denominator is a thing that can be done. That should have been the first thing I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace $z$ with $x+yi$, you get$$\frac{4 x^4+x^3+4 x^2-3 y^2 x+x-4 y^4+4 y^2}{\left(x^3-3xy^2+x\right)^2+\left(-y^3+3 x^2 y+y\right)^2}+\frac{-8 y x^3-3 y x^2-8 y^3 x+y^3-y}{\left(x^3-3xy^2+x\right)^2+\left(-y^3+3 x^2 y+y\right)^2}i.$$

Answer (score 0):

decompose $f$

after you're done with that you'll get

$f(z) = \frac{3}{z^2+1} +\frac1z = 3\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\arctan(z)) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \ln z = 3\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\arctan(x+iy)) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \ln (x+iy)$

and you have $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac12(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y})$

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just note that
$$f(z) = \frac{4z+1}{z(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$$
where $$p(z)=4z+1$$ and $$q(z)=z(z-i)(z+i)$$

Since $p$ and $q$ are analytic on $\mathbb C$, being polynomials, their ratio is analytic eveyrwhere $q\neq 0$, which is exactly $\mathbb C\setminus\{0,i,-i\}$.